# Pfsense breaks certification chain

Tags: ssl, pfsense, gcp

I have a problem I was thinking it was a simple one.
It seems it is not. Not from my point of vue :(

In the same GCP Project,
I have two independant VPC, one linked to the vtnet0 (LAN) of a pfsense 2.7.0, with no external IP.
The second one, linked to the vtnet1 (WAN) of the same pfsense, with an exernal IP.
Pfsense is commuting well for CE that are linked only to the LAN.

It pings well in reality.
It can curl well too.

But, I'm stick with the same eternal problem of SSL certification in the context of apt. All LAN ce will be debian12, for real.

If I try to `apt -y update` on a LAN ce :

```
Err:4 https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease                              
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificat
e does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification.
```

I'm done with DNS, the certification is usued (let's encrypt way).
I'm done with Firewalling and NAT.

I'm completely lost, and I cannot see a way to search for.
(I'm done with almost all the forum I already read ...).

Stack is my last chance :)

Comment: As far as I know Debian uses in default **http** and not **https** for downloading repositories. Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` text file and replace all entries of `https` with `http`.

Comment: In Bookworm stable context, default is now __https__. I prefer not to add legacy, you know ...